# ALL SQL-Update-Files will be executed when performing Update

Tags: joomla, sql-update, joomla3.0, joomla-component

In my update package I have a folder with some SQL-Files. There are all update file stored.

```
install.sql
update-00.sql
update-01.sql
update-02.sql
update-03.sql
update-04.sql
update-05.sql
update-06.sql
update-07.sql
```

When update from a version 04 to 05 also update files from version 01, 02, 03 and 04 will be executed.

My problem here is: Some SQL-Statements doesn't work for some reason and then the execution stops at this statement.

Is the behavior correct? And if yes, what do I have to do, to make it working.
If no, what is the correct usage of sql-folder and sql-files?

Best regards
DreiBaer

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! saves the current version of the database schema in the #__schema table. You can see the latest version of your extension with a SQL statement like this:

```
select * 
from #__schemas 
where extension_id in (
    select extension_id 
    from #__extensions 
    where element = 'com_eventgallery'
);
```

The latest version is set to the newest filename in your SQL update folder. Your idea how this should work is correct. Make sure your manifest is in `update` mode.

https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_(Update_SQL_files)